# JSONArray Parsing in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse a JSONArray but unable to do so. I am getting Null as reply

MY JSONArray:

```
["{\"mapurl\":\"http:\\\/\\\/maps.google.com\\\/maps?q=17.XXXXXXXX,78.xxxxxxx\",\"caller\":\"+91xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":1,\"reciever\":\"+91xxxxxxxx\",\"timpestamp\":\"3\"}","{\"mapurl\":\"http:\\\/\\\/maps.google.com\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxxxx,78.xxxxxxx\",\"caller\":\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":2,\"reciever\":\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\",\"timpestamp\":\"3\"}"]
```

I am passing this JSONArray from Android as a GET request in the parameter "add"

my PHP CODE:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
$jsonData = $_GET['add'];
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
var_dump($phpArray);
}
else{
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you perform `echo $_GET['add'];` at the top of your code?

Comment: @RichardBernards let me check

Comment: I strongly recommand to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: If you get NULL, your JSON isn't properly encoded. Use `if ($phpArray == null) echo json_last_error_msg();` to see the error.

Comment: @RichardBernards `[\"{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxx,78.xxxxxx\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91XXXXXXX\\\",\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91XXXXXXX\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\",\"{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxxx,78.xxxxxx\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxxxx\\\",\\\"id\\\":2,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxxxx\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\"]NULL`  this is the response that i am getting

Comment: Yeah... that's not valid JSON... Try using a POST and update your question with the way you generate this JSON...

Comment: As you are sending an array of objects, the objects shouldn't be between quotes. So use `[{...}]` instead of `["{...}"]`.

Comment: @ojovirtual it says `Call to undefined function  json_last_error_msg()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if your PHP configuration still has the deprecated [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) feature enabled. Either disable magic_quotes in your PHP configuration or try to remove the extra backslashes added by the magic_quotes feature with the `stripslashes()` function:

`$jsonData = stripslashes($_GET['add']);`

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with your json. It's actually valid. I think it's because you're using `$_GET` to pass the data. I suggest you use `post` to send the Json data. However, if you must use `$_GET` to send the data, make sure you `JSON.stringify()` it. But if your data will be longer than what you have here, you might have a truncated url which of course, is the data.

That way your current code is very valid, including your json.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is actually several json-encoded objects **stored as strings in a json  array**. Something funky going on with your encoder...

You can just loop through the array and decode each part:

```
$phpArray = array();
foreach(json_decode($_GET['add']) as $part) {
    $phpArray[] = json_decode($part, true);
}
```

But you should fix it at the source really!

Unsure why you're getting NULL though. You should at least get an array of strings back using your code. I tested myself and did...